# Results from logit model using BIOGEME unexpected

Tags: logistic, p-value, software, mlogit, clogit

I am using [BIOGEME](http://biogeme.epfl.ch/) to estimate the discrete choice model (choice is made among four alternative routes). I am having hard time with modeling using BIOGEME, and expecting help on this.

I have dataset in the following format:

[image]

Here, "a" and "s" are the variables describing each route. And the variable "CHOICE" means that 4th alternative is chosen( as 4th alternative is the actual route chosen by the individuals).

I updated the model specification file available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150123002644/http://biogeme.epfl.ch/swissmetro/python/01logit.py), and ran the model.
The result I am getting is like this:

[image]

The coefficients,t-stat and p-value are not correct, as seen from these values.

Anyone could help me fugure out what might be the problem with this?

Comment: Do you also have observations choosing the other alternatives? Otherwise, the model can't be estimated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try scaling your X's.  divide all the a's by 100.  It does not change anything except units and can help with the maximization as some of your X's (a) are in thousands while your (s)'s are double digits